# iOS5 UIManagedDocument and FetchedResultsController exception, on save change

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I have a tableViewController backed by a fetchedResultsController/UIManagedDocument that uses data fetched from a server via JSON messages. It is modeled on the TVC used in the Stanford 2011 iPhone programming lectures. The program loads, updates from the server and refreshes the tableView flawlessly. However when I try to edit the information in a cell, I have a very odd result.

I edit objects in a class PlugDetailTVC which messages the DataFetcher class to send an appropriate JSON message. Then the entire database is reloaded via
getAllPlugsInDocument. Everything works fine. the correct JSON is sent and the correct response is received. The server database updates correctly. after getAllPlugsInDocument runs, the tableView shows the correct updated information. Then 10-15 seconds later the program throws an exception with no error message!

UPDate: I made one change to my code which was  a change the saveToURL.document.fileURL to be

```
[self.document saveToURL:document.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting
                       completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
                           if (success) {                  
                               NSLog(@"PlugFetcher Document saved"); 
                           } else {                       
                               NSLog(@"PlugFetcher Document was unable to save");
                           }
```

BUT! I gave the code to someone else to run (xcode 4.2/iPhone 5.1 simulator with hack to run iOS 5.1) It ran perfectly! I then ran it on my phone- 4S with iOS 5.1 Again works perfectly. Back to iPhone 5.1 simulator on xCode 4.3.1- same old crash, even after reset contents and settings etc.
Now I am more mystified than before.

Relevant code:

PlugsTableViewController

```
-(void)setupFetchedResultsController{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context=self.mainDatabase.managedObjectContext;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Plug"];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
    self.fetchedResultsController= [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

}

-(void)fetchPlugDataIntoDocument:(UIManagedDocument *)document{
    NSLog(@"fetchPlugDataIntoDocument");
    PlugFetcher *plugFetcher=[PlugFetcher getInstance];
    [plugFetcher getAllTimeZones:document];
    [plugFetcher getAllPlugsInDocument:document];
}
//Open or create document,call setupFetchedResultsController

    -(void)useDocument{
          if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:[self.mainDatabase.fileURL path]]) {
            NSLog(@"######## Document Does not exist #########");

            [self.mainDatabase saveToURL:self.mainDatabase.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            [self setupFetchedResultsController];
            }];
        }else if (self.mainDatabase.documentState==UIDocumentStateClosed){
            NSLog(@"######## Document closed #########");
           [self.mainDatabase openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            [self setupFetchedResultsController];
             }];

        }else if (self.mainDatabase.documentState==UIDocumentStateNormal){
            NSLog(@"######## Document Normal #########");
           [self setupFetchedResultsController];
        }
        [self fetchPlugDataIntoDocument:self.mainDatabase];
    }

-(void)setmainDatabase:(UIManagedDocument *)mainDatabase{
    if (_mainDatabase!=mainDatabase) {
        _mainDatabase=mainDatabase;
        [self useDocument];
    }
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if (!self.mainDatabase) {
        NSLog(@"######## !self.mainDatabase #########");
        NSURL *url=[[[NSFileManager defaultManager]URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask]lastObject];
        url=[url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"main Database"];
        self.mainDatabase=[[UIManagedDocument alloc]initWithFileURL:url];
        PlugFetcher *plugFetcher=[PlugFetcher getInstance];
        plugFetcher.context=self.mainDatabase.managedObjectContext;
        plugFetcher.document=self.mainDatabase;

    }
}


PlugFetcher.m

- (void)getAllPlugsInDocument:(UIManagedDocument*)document{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context=[document managedObjectContext];    
    dispatch_queue_t fetchQ=dispatch_queue_create("Data Fetcher", NULL);
    dispatch_async(fetchQ, ^{
        NSDictionary *serverDictionary=[self.serverCommManager getServerPlugList];
        if([[serverDictionary objectForKey:@"success"] isEqualToString:@"true"]){
            NSArray *serverPlugArray=[serverDictionary objectForKey:@"response"];

            [document.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{ // perform in the NSMOC's safe thread (main thread)
                NSEntityDescription *plugEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Plug" inManagedObjectContext:context];
                [self deleteAllObjectsInEntity:plugEntity forPlug:nil inContext:context];  
                NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"TimeZone"];
                request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"utcOffset"
                                                                                                 ascending:YES]];
                NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
                [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];
                for (NSDictionary *plugFromServer in serverPlugArray){
                    Plug *newLocalPlug=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Plug" inManagedObjectContext:context];
                    newLocalPlug.plugID = [plugFromServer valueForKey:@"id"];
                    newLocalPlug.name = [plugFromServer valueForKey:@"name"];
                    newLocalPlug.location = [plugFromServer valueForKey:@"loc"];
                    newLocalPlug.notes = [plugFromServer valueForKey:@"notes"];
                    newLocalPlug.state=[plugFromServer valueForKey:@"state"];
                }
                [document saveToURL:document.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting completionHandler:NULL];
            }];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"PLUGFETCHER  getAllPlugs:json response=fail");        
        }
    });
}

-(void)updatePlug:(Plug*)plug{
    NSString *json = [JSONQuery queryUpdateDevice:plug.plugID 
                                             name:plug.name 
                                         location:plug.location
                                            notes:plug.notes
                                            dummy:plug.dummy 
                                            state:plug.state
                                         timezone:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", plug.timeZone.utcOffset]];    
    [self.serverCommManager send:json];
}



PlugDetailTVC:

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"savePlugDetail"]){

        //forces saving of info in field be edited when button is pushed
        [self.view.window endEditing: YES];
        [self.currentTextField endEditing:YES];
         NSLog(@"PlugDetailTVC prepareForSeque plug:%@",self.plug.plugID);
        PlugFetcher *plugFetcher= [PlugFetcher getInstance];
        [plugFetcher updatePlug:self.plug];
}
```